# java Collections for retrieving values from a huge list

Tags: java, data-structures

I have an Excel file, from which we have to retrieve the data. There will be 
 multiple sections, so each section will be stored in an `ArrayList` which will be added to the main `ArrayList` and will be used.

Now we have a requirement, where I will be getting few values which I have to use for retrieving the other values of the section.

If I use `ArrayList`, for each value, I have to loop through the complete list and once a match is found, I have to retrieve its corresponding value.

If I use `HashMap`, just for retrieving few values (5 records) from the list, I have to store 2000 records to the map.

Can anyone suggest me a best way for storing and retrieval of these data.

Comment: _Can anyone suggest me a best way for storing and retrieval of these datas._: Use a database.

Answer (score 0):

give you some advise:
1. maybe you should find some tool for free to sql in excel.
2. maybe you should create index firstly by yourcode in excel or memory for performance, and then do the query

Comment: yeah, we already had a thought of using a database, but apart from using a database, is there any other way from which i can get this done?